# Tic Tac Toe in C++ (console version)

Tags: c++, game, tic-tac-toe

I have made a 2 player Tic Tac Toe game in C++. I have put in some error checking also (like if the players enters an invalid position). The code is working absolutely fine.
This is what my program output looks like.

```
         |       |       |

         |       |       |

         |       |       |
Where you want to make move: 1        

        cross    |       |

         |       |       |

         |       |       |
Where you want to make move: 2        

        cross   zero     |

         |       |       |

         |       |       |
Where you want to make move: 4        

        cross   zero     |

        cross    |       |

         |       |       |
Where you want to make move: 3        

        cross   zero    zero

        cross    |       |

         |       |       |
Where you want to make move: 7        

        cross   zero    zero

        cross    |       |

        cross    |       |
Player 1 is WINNNER!
```

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define Player1 1
#define Player2 2

int whoseTurn;

string moves[3] = {"empty", "cross", "zero"};
string board[9] = {"empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty"};
//An array to avoid duplicate input
int playedPos[9] = {0};

void printBoard()
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (i == 3 || i == 6)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        if (board[i] == "empty")
        {
            cout << "\t"
                 << " | ";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\t" << board[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//Checking if any paper has won
bool check_for_victory(string board[])
{
    if ((board[0] != "empty") && (board[0] == board[1]) && (board[1] == board[2]))
        return true;
    if ((board[3] != "empty") && (board[3] == board[4]) && (board[4] == board[5]))
        return true;
    if ((board[6] != "empty") && (board[6] == board[7]) && (board[7] == board[8]))
        return true;
    if ((board[0] != "empty") && (board[0] == board[3]) && (board[3] == board[6]))
        return true;
    if ((board[1] != "empty") && (board[1] == board[4]) && (board[4] == board[7]))
        return true;
    if ((board[2] != "empty") && (board[2] == board[5]) && (board[5] == board[8]))
        return true;
    if ((board[0] != "empty") && (board[0] == board[4]) && (board[4] == board[8]))
        return true;
    if ((board[6] != "empty") && (board[6] == board[4]) && (board[4] == board[2]))
        return true;
    return false;
}

void makeMove(int whoseTurn)
{
    //Variable for counting how many times the game is played
    int gameCount = 0;
    int pos, move;
    while ((check_for_victory(board) == false) && (gameCount != 9))
    {
        cout << "Where you want to make move: ";
        cin >> pos;
        if (pos < 10 && pos > 0) //Checking if the user entered a valid move
        {
            pos--;
            //incrementing the position at the pos index to 1
            playedPos[pos]++;
            if (playedPos[pos] <= 1)
            {
                if (whoseTurn == Player1)
                {
                    move = Player1;
                    board[pos] = moves[move];
                    printBoard();
                    whoseTurn = Player2;
                    gameCount++;
                }
                else if (whoseTurn == Player2)
                {
                    move = Player2;
                    board[pos] = moves[move];
                    printBoard();
                    whoseTurn = Player1;
                    gameCount++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You have played this move" << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Enter a valid position" << endl;
        }
    }

    if ((check_for_victory(board) == false) && gameCount != 9)
    {
        cout << "Math is draw" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (whoseTurn == Player1)
        {
            cout << "Player 2 is WINNER!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Player 1 is WINNNER!" << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    whoseTurn = Player1;
    printBoard();
    makeMove(Player1);
}
```

I want to know that have I done it right as it is my first time.

Comment: Your code is far from working as intended what it's supposed to do. Please make your code woking first before asking fo a review here.

Comment: For those considering VTC: the code [works fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SjrjqrbZidMKNQ4c) now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Player identification

```
#define Player1 1
#define Player2 2

int whoseTurn;
```

Do you ever plan to support more than two players? If not, consider representing this as `enum` or a `bool`.

The same is true of your `moves` and `board`. Those should not be strings; they should be enums. Making them strings is not strongly-typed, and gives you fewer guarantees about the correctness of the code. So avoid "stringly-typed" code.

### Don't repeat yourself

In `check_for_victory`, note that those statements all look virtually identical except for the indexes. So factor out the indexes into an array of integers and loop over them.

### Boolean expressions

```
(check_for_victory(board) == false) && (gameCount != 9)
```

should be

```
!check_for_victory(board) && gameCount < 9
```

### Consolidation of logic

This doesn't need an if:

```
            if (whoseTurn == Player1)
            {
                move = Player1;
                board[pos] = moves[move];
                printBoard();
                whoseTurn = Player2;
                gameCount++;
            }
```

As your code stands currently, you can just do

```
move = whoseTurn;
board[pos] = moves[move];
printBoard();
whoseTurn = N_PLAYERS - whoseTurn + 1;
gameCount++;
```